# run powershell script in the background, even if the system gets locked

Tags: powershell, scripting

the powershell script halts its execution, when ever the system gets locked. Once we unlock the system, the script continues its execution.

Is there a way by which we can continue the powershell script execution, even if the system is locked ?

The script clicks on specific points in local system after opening the explorer. Then it opens the remote desktop connection, then again clicks on specific points in the remote system. This behavior is in a loop, so that it simulates a human interaction with the remote system from the local system.

Our ultimate goal is to avoid the 15 minutes timeout restriction that we have in remote desktop connection and also the server goes for a restart after few hours due to inactivity.

Powershell Script :

```
 $cSource = @'
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class Clicker
{
//https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646270(v=vs.85).aspx
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct INPUT
{ 
    public int        type; // 0 = INPUT_MOUSE,
                            // 1 = INPUT_KEYBOARD
                            // 2 = INPUT_HARDWARE
    public MOUSEINPUT mi;
}

//https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646273(v=vs.85).aspx
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct MOUSEINPUT
{
    public int    dx ;
    public int    dy ;
    public int    mouseData ;
    public int    dwFlags;
    public int    time;
    public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
}

//This covers most use cases although complex mice may have additional buttons
//There are additional constants you can use for those cases, see the msdn page
const int MOUSEEVENTF_MOVED      = 0x0001 ;
const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN   = 0x0002 ;
const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP     = 0x0004 ;
const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN  = 0x0008 ;
const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP    = 0x0010 ;
const int MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN = 0x0020 ;
const int MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP   = 0x0040 ;
const int MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL      = 0x0080 ;
const int MOUSEEVENTF_XDOWN      = 0x0100 ;
const int MOUSEEVENTF_XUP        = 0x0200 ;
const int MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE   = 0x8000 ;

const int screen_length = 0x10000 ;

//https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
extern static uint SendInput(uint nInputs, INPUT[] pInputs, int cbSize);

public static void LeftClickAtPoint(int x, int y)
{
    //Move the mouse
    INPUT[] input = new INPUT[3];
    input[0].mi.dx = x*(65535/System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width);
    input[0].mi.dy = y*(65535/System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
    input[0].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_MOVED | MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE;
    //Left mouse button down
    input[1].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
    //Left mouse button up
    input[2].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
    SendInput(3, input, Marshal.SizeOf(input[0]));
}
}
'@
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $cSource -ReferencedAssemblies System.Windows.Forms,System.Drawing
Add-Type -AssemblyName microsoft.VisualBasic
#Send a click at a specified point
$current_date = Get-Date -Format "MM-dd-yyyy_hh-mm-ss"
$LogFile = 'I:\'+'click_activity_'+$current_date+".txt"
for($i=1; $i -lt 1440; $i = $i + 1)
        {
        Write-Host "the current minute number is $i `n " 
        Write-Host "press ctrl+ C to stop execution `n "
        explorer .
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
        [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("% x");
        [Clicker]::LeftClickAtPoint(64,233)
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
        $current_time = Get-Date        
        Add-Content $LogFile "left click on 64,233 by $current_time and minute number is $i"
        [Clicker]::LeftClickAtPoint(64,258)     
        explorer .
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
        [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("% x");
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
        $current_time = Get-Date        
        Add-Content $LogFile  "left click on 64,433 by $current_time and minute number is $i"
        $close_explorer = (New-Object -comObject Shell.Application).Windows() |
         ? { $_.FullName -ne $null} |
         ? { $_.FullName.toLower().Endswith('\explorer.exe') } 

         $close_explorer | % {  $_.Quit() }
         Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
         [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::AppActivate("Remote Desktop Connection")
         Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
         [Clicker]::LeftClickAtPoint(64,233)
         Start-Sleep -Seconds 3
         [Clicker]::LeftClickAtPoint(64,258)    
         Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
         #[system.diagnostics.process]::Start()
        }
```

Comment: Why not ask the admin to change the timeout? Trying to circumvent restrictions set by admin is usually very bad idea.

Comment: @vonPryz yes it is a bad idea, but we don't have a choice. Admin cannot change the default setting due to internal restrictions.

Comment: I'm not a powershell whiz, but it seems the problem is the script running as the USER such that when the session goes to sleep and locks, it suspends the script as well. Can you run the script as a system process that will ignore a user session lock?

Comment: Trying to circumvent policy set by company / school / whatever is a sure-fire way to get yourself in trouble. Image what would happen if someone abuses the system because it hasn't been locked down? Then you get all the blame as your trick prevented the lockdown. Do yourself a favor and escalate the case to get appropriate permissions.